Default applications in linux open suse leap 15?
Description:
Have linux open suse leap ~15!!!
Can't open org.kde.discover.desktop file which located in /home/etc/Documents/Apps/ in folder by created me.
Problems:

May be I removed something and now any (AnyApp.desktop) is could not opened in my linux system.
This is my 1'st problem today.

Snapshots is not working also.


I Try:

And when I was try opening any .desktop file by (double click) it just was opened with libreoffice application (calc) but it's impossible.
In Settings/Applcations/No any workable associated application. (except for the calc).


Someone help me.

I edited. Then you.
